# AppDomain recycle and partial postback

Tags: iis, asp.net-ajax, appdomain

I am having an issue where partial post-backs in ASP.NET cease to work when the IIS AppDomain recycles.

The scenario is this. I have a dashboard type web app that checks for updates at a timed interval through partial ajax post-backs. When I release updates to the web server and the AppDomain recycles the post-backs stop working unless the user refreshes the page. Since this is an app that stays up all day and is being monitored for changes without user input it can be a problem if suddenly it just stops updating.

How do I prevent the partial post-backs from stopping to work without a full page refresh post Session loss? And if that's not possible, how do I detect that the session has been lost from javascript so I can force a full page refresh?

Comment: You’ll have to find out why it happens. There are many possibilities. If it’s about session getting lost then save the session out of process so it doesn’t get lost

Comment: I already know why the session gets lost. I explained it above. Its because I updated the site with new code and that cycles the AppDomain. I can rebuild all the stuff I store in the session no problem but not if the timed partial post-backs stops working. I need a solution for how to not have that stop working.

Comment: As I said, store session outside or do something else. Without any information about your application can’t say anything else. And you assumed session state would be the issue, that’s why I asked you to find out the reason for your application not working first rather than wondering. If it’s the session then solution is simple.

Comment: I don't know what else is there to find out. This problem is not particular to my application. Any ajax partial post-back ceases to post if the AppDomain of the web server is cycled. The Ajax partial post-back is Microsoft's code not mine. If the page can somehow detect when this happens I could solve this easily with a forced page refresh which solves the issue. But I don't know how to detect if the AppDomain has been cycled from javascript.

Comment: "I assume the session state is lost", and then why cannot you add application level logging (ASP.NET does expose session related events) to track session state? That can easily confirm your assumption, or point you to other causes. Knowing exactly the cause of the issue can lead you to a solution, but right now you just need to dig further.

Comment: Yes the session is lost by the AppDomain recycle. I have no issues with the session being lost. Could we please get beyond the fact that the Session is lost and get into the actual question I had which is, now that it is lost, how do I prevent the partial post-backs from stopping to work without a full page refresh? And if that's not possible, how do I detect that the session has been lost from javascript so I can force a full page refresh?